# How can I share a cookie between sibling subdomains?

Tags: express, cookies

I have an Express.js API at api.mysite.com

I have a frontend I am writing at dev.mysite.com

I have a login page at dev.mysite.com/login

On login submission it POSTS the users credentials to api.mysite.com/login_attempt, where the following code is run:

```
    res.cookie ( "token", token, { 
      httpOnly: true, 
      domain: ".mysite.com",
      secure: true
    } );
```

My understanding is that domain should allow the cookie to be accessed on both api.mysite.com and dev.mysite.com.

In the network response headers for the request I see:

```
Set-Cookie: token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.S1x3jECfXfFa0Y0ZGs8QCVJQLLNfVZFaA1AwArWsCdo; Domain=.mysite.com; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure
```

Not the `Domain=.mysite.com;` at the end.

However after the request has been made, if I open the Chrome inspector > Application > Cookies, it is nowhere to be seen. I also am not seemingly able to access it in my frontend code.

Have I misunderstood how cross-subdomain cookies work? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If you are using fetch() to do the request, you might need to set `credentials` to `include`